# Removing duplicate rows that are not in a link table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

Using SQL Server 2008. I am trying to remove some duplicate rows in a table. Here are listed the tables and the columns that are relevant:

```
ItemTable
----------
Id - autoincrement, PK
ItemLabel - the actual identifier of the items


Linktable
----------
Id - autoincrement, PK
ItemId - the Id from ItemTable
RelatedItemId - the Id from RelatedItemTable


RelatedItemTable
------
no need to touch this with the query..
```

**So the link table does not contain the actual id of the items, but the running row number from the two tables**

What needs to be achieved: ItemTable contains rows that have a duplicate ItemLabel, where the other is listed in link table (with the Id column's value) and the other is not. From ItemTable the ones that are not linked have to be removed. I know how to select the duplicate rows using count and group by but haven't been able to figure out how to delete only the ones that are not existing in the link table. ItemTable also contains duplicates of items with no relation, one of them must remain (does not matter which).

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d181 Here is an SQL fiddle with dummy data.

P.S. Don't ask why the link table uses the running id instead of the actual id (that could be PK'd)... it's a legacy system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
DELETE t
OUTPUT deleted.*
FROM    ItemTable t
JOIN    (
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemLabel ORDER BY lt.ItemID DESC, it.id) num
        , it.Id
 FROM   ItemTable it
 LEFT JOIN 
        LinkTable lt ON
        lt.ItemId = it.id
) t2 ON t2.Id = t.Id
WHERE num > 1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf299/14/0)**

Although the above described approach works for your situation, I suggest approach which is more readable and over which you'll have more control and a better overview. 
It's a multi-step approach in which each step can be analyzed and tested:

```
-- get ItemLabels of duplicate records
SELECT  ItemLabel
INTO    #Duplicate_ItemLabels
FROM    ItemTable it
GROUP BY
        it.ItemLabel
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1

-- get ItemLabels of duplicate records that have at least one record related to LinkTable
SELECT  *
INTO    #Duplicate_ItemLabels_Related_To_LinkTable
FROM    #Duplicate_ItemLabels d1
WHERE   EXISTS
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    ItemTable it
        JOIN    Linktable lt ON 
                lt.ItemID = it.ID
        WHERE   it.ItemLabel = d1.ItemLabel
)

-- get ItemLabels of duplicate records that don't have any records related to LinkTable
SELECT  ItemLabel
INTO    #Duplicate_ItemLabels_NOT_Related_To_LinkTable
FROM    #Duplicate_ItemLabels
EXCEPT
SELECT  ItemLabel
FROM    #Duplicate_ItemLabels_Related_To_LinkTable

-- delete unwanted records for ItemLabels that have records related to linkTable
DELETE  it
OUTPUT  deleted.*
FROM    ItemTable it
JOIN    #Duplicate_ItemLabels_Related_To_LinkTable dup ON
        dup.ItemLabel = it.ItemLabel
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Linktable lt
        WHERE   lt.ItemID = it.ID
)

-- delete unwanted records for ItemLabels that don't have any records related to linkTable
DELETE  it
OUTPUT  deleted.*
FROM    ItemTable it
JOIN    #Duplicate_ItemLabels_NOT_Related_To_LinkTable dup ON
        dup.ItemLabel = it.ItemLabel
JOIN    
(
        -- records deleted will be all those that have ID greater than the smallest ID for this ItemLabel
        SELECT  ItemLabel
                , MIN(ID) ID
        FROM    ItemTable dup
        GROUP BY
                dup.ItemLabel
)       gr ON
        gr.ID < it.ID
AND     gr.ItemLabel = dup.ItemLabel

-- if after these DELETEs there are still duplicate records, it 
-- means that there are records for same ItemLabel with 
-- different ID and all of them are related to LinkTable
```

You can easily modify it, test results and manipulate which records will be deleted. I created a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31011/3/2) in which I put different samples of data so you can see how it is being handled.

To sample data of a second approach I also added records in `ItemTable` where you have same `ItemLabel` with different `ID` of which more than one is related to `LinkTable` (none of them gets deleted arbitrarily).

Comment: The first two would delete all duplicate rows AFAIK, the problem here is that the duplicate that is in the link table must remain intact. The third query returned nothing when I changed the DELETE to SELECT * ..

Comment: @TeemuTerho The best thing would be to post some sample data along with the expected output. If you do that I'm sure quite a lot of people here could give you the answer :)

Comment: @TeemuTerho I updated my answer, I believe it does what is expected, see the SQL Fiddle...

Comment: I will test it, I was working on the solution JW provided (which is very close). I'll give yours a try, too, since it is a different approach. I should also update the description since it doesn't have all the information. Busy busy busy working on it :)

Comment: @TeemuTerho I added new query and new SQL Fiddle, try it :)

Comment: On the fiddle data works as expected - on actual data removes a lot (10x more than expected) of valid links too.. something is still not right with this and my limited SQL skills are not enough to point out the fault :( I'll accept this if JW doesn't deliver since this works correctly on the fiddle.

Comment: OK, I think I know why this is happening, same `ItemID` is occuring multiple times in `Linktable`, I'll fix it...

Comment: @TeemuTerho Can you please try it, I fixed it and added row `(5, 5, 10)` to `LinkTable`'s sample data to show that problem with multiple `LinkTable.ItemId` is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Join both table using `LEFT JOIN`. Obviously non existent `ItemTable.ID` will have *null* values on `Linktable.ItemID` and this will be filtered in your `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    ItemTable a
        LEFT JOIN Linktable b
            ON a.ID = b.ItemID
WHERE   b.ItemID IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried doing a select with this query, it seems like it returned also the non-duplicate rows. Only the ones that are duplicate and not in the link table can be removed. Thx for the formatting edit btw :)

Comment: can you give sample records atleast 4 per table `:D` with match and nonmatching data so we can play with it `:D`

Comment: Would rather not do that, will be easier for me to consult an IRL SQL-wizard later in the day if this doesn't get solved with only the description.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cb13/1 I remodeled this to reflect the data I'm working on.

Comment: so in other words, only `1,5,6` will remain? I think you mean `1,3,4,5`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25940/discussion-between-jw-and-teemu-terho)

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear in the SQL comments - only 2 must be removed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99b00

Comment: I tried the last fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/889d6/1) we agreed on in the chat, but it seems that for some records it returns both rows, the linked one and the duplicate that is not linked. For some it works correctly.

Comment: This happens only on actual data. To my eye they seem like all the other ones - I can't see any reason why the behaviour is different for some than the others. I will see if i can replicate the problem in an SQLfiddle.

Comment: There are also duplicates of items that are not in the link table, and they shouldn't be since there is no relation. The problem with the solution is that one of them must remain (does not matter which one). Now they both get removed because the logic is to remove all duplicates that are not in the link table.

Comment: your solution is very close if you can figure out a way to keep one of the non-related duplicates. In my eyes you've earned the answer already since I didn't mention this problem in the original description. I updated the question so will we try to work with the new discoveries or do I cancel the updates and accept your solution for the original question?

Comment: Actually it's up to you, i have a follow up question, This fiddle has been modified to return duplicates which have no link, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc0cb/1, what will I do with this? delete all or delete only one?

Comment: Delete only one of the non-linked items.